# Angular 2/4 filtering dropdown in a ngFor with specific searchtext

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui

Hi I am trying to display three dropdown using *ngFor using same list of users. However on each drop I am using filter to display certain type of users in each dropdown.

In my view I am using *ngFor to loop to display three dropdowns.
Than using filter I am filtering certain results

```
         <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <md-select name="aId" [ngModel]="rout?.aId"  (ngModelChange)="rout.aId=$event" (change)="changedept(rout.aId)">
                      <md-option *ngFor="let user of users | userFilter: qUsers y" [value]="user._id">{{user.username}}</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
         </table>
check(doc){   
     for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      this.qUsers='';
       if(i==0){
         this.qUsers='Dev';
       }
      if(i==1){
         this.qUsers='Prod';
       }
       if(i==2){
        this.qUsers='Eng';
      }


@Pipe({ name: 'userFilter' ,
       pure: false
})
export class UserFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(users: IUser[],  searchTerm: string) : IUser[] {
  if(!users || !searchTerm) {
    return users
  }
  return users.filter(user =>user.department.deptname.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1 )

   }
}
```

Code is working fine. It is filtering too. However the problem is in each dropdown it shows same filtered result which is based upon the last qUsers used which is "Eng"
Please let me know how to make it display each dropdown with filtered using Dev, Prod and Eng. 
Thanks